# Retrieve rows in SQL based on Maximum value in multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, multiple-columns

I have a SQL table with the following fields:

- Company ID
- Company Name
- Fiscal Year
- Fiscal Quarter

There are multiple records for various fiscal years and fiscal quarters for each company. I want to retrieve the rows for each company based on Maximum Fiscal Year and Maximum Fiscal Quarter. For example, if the table has the following:

```
Company ID  |  Company Name  |  Fiscal Year | Fiscal Quarter 
1           |  Test1         |  2017        | 1
1           |  Test1         |  2017        | 2
1           |  Test1         |  2018        | 1
1           |  Test1         |  2018        | 2
2           |  Test2         |  2018        | 3
2           |  Test2         |  2018        | 4
```

The query should return the following (Only the record with the maximum fiscal year and maximum fiscal quarter for that year):

```
Company ID  |  Company Name  |  Fiscal Year | Fiscal Quarter 
1           |  Test1         |  2018        | 2
2           |  Test2         |  2018        | 4
```

I am able to use the below query to get the records with the maximum fiscal year but not sure how to further select the maximum quarter within the year:

```
SELECT fp.companyId, fp.companyname, fp.fiscalyear,fp.fiscalquarter
FROM  dbo.ciqFinPeriod fp
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ciqFinPeriod fp2
    ON (fp.companyId = fp2.companyId AND fp.fiscalyear < fp2.fiscalyear)
WHERE fp2.companyId IS NULL
```

Thank you so much for any assistance!

Comment: Do you have the CompanyName is this table? That seems like a normalization issue to say the least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a list of companies, I would simply do:

```
select fp.*
from Companies c outer apply
     (select top (1) fp.*
      from dbo.ciqFinPeriod fp
      where fp.companyId = c.companyId
      order by fp.fiscalyear desc, fp.fiscalquarter desc
     ) fp;
```

If not, then `row_number()` is probably the simplest method:

```
select fp.*
from (select fp.*,
             row_number() over (partition by fp.companyId order by order by fp.fiscalyear desc, fp.fiscalquarter desc) as seqnum
      from dbo.ciqFinPeriod fp
     ) fp
where seqnum = 1;
```

Or the somewhat more abstruse (clever ?):

```
select top (1) with ties fp.*
from dbo.ciqFinPeriod fp
order by row_number() over (partition by fp.companyId order by order by fp.fiscalyear desc, fp.fiscalquarter desc)
```

Comment: I'm a fan of the WITH TIES version. Abstruse and clever often walk hand in hand.

Comment: Thanks so much! Both the second and third options work great and its also very efficient!

Answer (score 0):

I've had some success with the following, same output as you.

```
create table #table
(
CompanyID int,
CompanyName varchar(200),
Year int,
Quater int
)

insert into #table (CompanyID,CompanyName,Year,Quater)
VALUES

('1','Test1','2017','1'),
('1','Test1','2017','2'),
('1','Test1','2018','1'),
('1','Test1','2018','2'),
('2','Test2','2018','3'),
('2','Test2','2018','4')

SELECT CompanyID,CompanyName,Year,Quater  
FROM
(

Select CompanyID,CompanyName,Year,Quater
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CompanyID ORDER BY Year desc,Quater DESC)         
as RowNum
from #table

) X  WHERE RowNum = 1

drop table #table
```

Answer (score 0):

Select Company I'd, company name,Max(year),Max(quarter) group by 1,2

Comment: Is this you r expecting??